# Open channels to bot without azure

Tags: botframework

I have a bot created in Azure, and I want to know if it is possible to open channels for this bot without having to go to Azure, ie through Visual Studio or another tool.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Marcelo,
Unfortunately, you can only configure bot channels through the Azure portal. There are currently no options for automation, REST API, etc. More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if it is possible to open channels for this bot without having to go to Azure

Azure bot service provides a way to easily and conveniently connect a bot to various channels, if you want to connect to the specific channel(s) without Azure, you can check if the specific channel(s) expose REST API for exchanging messages, and then you can try to write your own channel connectors that would take Activity objects and translate them back and forth into the specific channel's message schema.

***Note:***

1) This [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4340) discussed "*Is it possible to use the BotFramework SDK to connect to channels (telegram, skype...) without need to pay any Azure service?*", you can check it.

2) [The Bot Framework Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#connect-to-a-bot-running-on-local-host) works on local, you can connect to a bot running locally.